# Tkinter image not being shown on the proper page

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am very new to Python and coding in general, so be gentle with my code. Im trying to create a gui that has multiple windows with actions you can perform on each one. I want to have some pictures shown on a few of the pages to give the user an idea of what they are choosing. The image on my "home page" is displayed correctly, however when I try to open a page that should have another image on it, the image is instead displayed on the home page, not on its target page. Below are the blocks of code that the issue is occurring in, to the best of my knowledge. Let me know if I need to add any more information :)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args, *kwargs)
        self.config(bg='gray')
        self.title('Functionality')
        self.geometry('560x400')
        test_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Python Tests\\pics\\test.jpg'))
        self.label2 = tk.Label(image=test_img)
        self.label2.photo = test_img
        self.label2.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Please Select a Choice Below', font=('Arial Bold', 30), bg='gray')
        self.label.grid(column=1, row=1)
        self.button_retorque = tk.Button(self, text='Re-torque', command=lambda: reTorque())
        self.button_retorque.grid(column=1, row=3, pady=10)
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text='Close Application', command=self.destroy)
        self.quit.grid(column=1, row=5, pady=10)

class reTorque(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, *kwargs)
        self.config(bg='gray')
        self.geometry('750x400')
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='This is for a Re-torque', font=('Arial Bold', 30), bg='gray')
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Set Board Type Odd', command=boardOdd)
        self.button3.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10)
        self.button = tk.Button(self,text='Close', command=self.destroy)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=5)
        self.grab_set()

class boardOdd(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.config(bg='gray')
        self.geometry('500x400')
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Select Number of Odd Boards', font=('Arial Bold', 12), bg='gray')
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        odd_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\Python Tests\\pics\\odd.jpg'))
        self.label2 = tk.Label(image=odd_img)
        self.label2.photo = odd_img
        self.label2.grid(column=2, row=0)
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, text='1')
        self.button1.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=10)
        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, text='2')
        self.grab_set()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Main()
    app.mainloop()
```

Edit: Turns out I missed a very important part. Thanks to acw1668 and jasonharper for letting me know. Fixed by changing to

```
self.label2 = tk.Label(self,image=test_img)
```

Comment: You aren't consistently passing the parent widget - that should always be the first parameter when creating a widget.

Comment: You didn't specify the parent to `self.label2` in `boardOdd`, so the root window will be assigned.